# why the program cannot count the number? c language

Tags: c, count, minesweeper

i am making a minesweeper game in c language. in this stage, i want to the program to count the number of mines in specific row or column. what the program supposed to do is that after the user input the locations of the mines, he can count the no. of mines in specific row by typing 1 (row no.) or count the no. of mines in specific col by typing 2(col no.). however, my program cannot count the no. and always print out 0. i can't figure out why. plz kindly help me t o find out the problems of my program

[here is the pictures that show what my program do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fujbk.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Possible square states.
#define VISIBLE_SAFE    0
#define HIDDEN_SAFE     1
#define HIDDEN_MINE     2

// The size of the starting grid.
#define SIZE 8

// The possible command codes.
#define DETECT_ROW              1
#define DETECT_COL              2
#define DETECT_SQUARE           3
#define REVEAL_SQUARE           4
#define GAMEPLAY_MODE           5
#define DEBUG_MODE              6
#define REVEAL_RADIAL           7

// Add any extra #defines here.

void initialise_field(int minefield[SIZE][SIZE]);
void print_debug_minefield(int minefield[SIZE][SIZE]);

// Place your function prototyes here.

int main(void) {
int minefield[SIZE][SIZE];
int mines;
int pair1, pair2;
int detect;
int count = 0;
initialise_field(minefield);
printf("Welcome to minesweeper!\n");
printf("How many mines? ");
scanf("%d",&mines);

// TODO: Scan in the number of pairs of mines.

printf("Enter pairs:\n");
for( int i = 0; i < mines; i++){
scanf("%d %d",&pair1, &pair2);
minefield[pair1][pair2] = HIDDEN_MINE;
}
// TODO: Scan in the pairs of mines and place them on the grid.

printf("Game Started\n");
print_debug_minefield(minefield);
while(scanf("%d %d", &detect, &pair2) != EOF){
if ( detect == DETECT_ROW){
  for( int i = 0; i < pair2; i++){
    if(minefield[pair2][i] == HIDDEN_MINE){
      count++;
    }       
  }
  printf("There are %d mine(s) in row %d\n",count,pair2);
  print_debug_minefield(minefield);
}
else if( detect == DETECT_COL){
  for(int j = 0; j < pair2; j++){
    if( minefield[j][pair2] == HIDDEN_MINE){
      count++;
      
    }
  }
  printf("There are %d mine(s) in column %d\n",count,pair2);
  print_debug_minefield(minefield);
 }
}


// TODO: Scan in commands to play the game until the game ends.
// A game ends when the player wins, loses, or enters EOF (Ctrl+D).
// You should display the minefield after each command has been processed.

return 0;
}

// Set the entire minefield to HIDDEN_SAFE.
void initialise_field(int minefield[SIZE][SIZE]) {
int i = 0;
while (i < SIZE) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < SIZE) {
        minefield[i][j] = HIDDEN_SAFE;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
 }
}

// Print out the actual values of the minefield.
void print_debug_minefield(int minefield[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < SIZE) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < SIZE) {
        printf("%d ", minefield[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? That is, trace the program in a debugger and/or add debug print statements. If already done what did you find? Where do things start going wrong?

Comment: `pair2` seems to be row or column which you want to scan in search of any mine, but the loops you use only traverse from 0 to (excluded) `pair2`, instead of the *whole* row or column (up to `SIZE`). In your example, the mines happen to have coordinates (`pair2`, `pair2`).

Comment: @Bob__ it works now. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In line `minefield[pair1][pair2] = HIDDEN_MINE` set mines in below co-ordinate.
(0 0), (1 1), (2 2)

But in below code.

```
for( int i = 0; i < pair2; i++){
    if(minefield[pair2][i] == HIDDEN_MINE){
      count++;
    }
```

It only verifies co-ordinate (pair2, 0 to (pair2-1) ) whereas HIDDEN_MINE values are in co-ordinate (0-pair1, pair2).
So loop to be executed till pair2 not (pair2 -1).

```
  for( int i = 0; i <= pair2; i++) // Will modify count properly
```

Comment: Please note that to check an *entire* row or column the loop should be executed till `i < SIZE`.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, i missed that part, only pointed where was the actual problem. Thanks for pointing out though.